# How to divide an image in X equal parts

Tags: image-processing

I am working to create a Google group for Ubuntu but one thing I want to do is create the main image that goes in the top (The one that divides into 5 pieces). How can I divide an image horizontally (Or vertically) via Terminal or GUI.

For example I grab an Ubuntu Quantal image and tell a GUI or terminal program to divide the image in 5 equal parts horizontally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install [ImageMagick](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/imagemagick), and then use the command `convert`:

```
convert -crop 20%x100% rose.jpg rose2.jpg
```

Explanation:

- `20%` is 1/5 of 100% and therefore will crop the image in 5 equal parts.
- `100%` so that it will not be cropped vertically.
- `rose.jpg` is the original file.
- `rose2.jpg` is the output.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Was going to ask about the % before going for the --help of the command. Is there an option to crop it vertically. I would think to first flip it 90 degrees then crop it, then flip it back -90 degrees but maybe there is another way.

Comment: Just invert the command 20%x100% to 100%x20%: `convert -crop 100%x20% rose.jpg rose2.jpg`

Comment: Amazing really. Very easy to know and apply.