# Wallpaper slideshow software that supports changing image size

Tags: desktop-background, slideshow

I've found several software applications that create slideshows, but I've yet to see one that support changing the image size (i.e. fit, stretch, fill width, fill height). Is there any software that supports this?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but... can always be made. What exactly would you like it to do?

Comment: Might I suggest using ImageMagick in a bash script to resize your images as you want and then running your currently being used Wallpaper Slideshwo Software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Introduction

Here's the thing: if you run in terminal `dconf watch /` and at the same time flip through options in Ubuntu settings for the wallpaper size ( Tile, Scale, Zoom, etc.) you will see this:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'zoom'

/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'wallpaper'

/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'centered'

/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'scaled'

/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'stretched'

/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-options
  'spanned'
```

What does it all mean ? This means that if you have a software that can flip through wallpaper, it also should be able to flip through those options, right ?

Well, I've written a wallpaper [slide-show script some time before](https://askubuntu.com/a/820269/295286). In the past it had required options. For your specific question, I modified the script to also deal with size, as well as made only one option required `-d` which corresponds to the directory where slideshow images are supposed to live.

#### Basic Usage

The usage is simple: give it directory with images, give it size , and run. It is as simple as doing this:

```
 $ ./xml_wallpaper_maker.py -s zoom  -d ~/Pictures/wallpapers/
```

You can always use `-h` option to show help information for extra options too and in case you forget the usage:

```
$ ./xml_wallpaper_maker.py -h                                                                                                         
usage: xml_wallpaper_maker.py [-h] -d DIRECTORY [-t TRANSITION] [-l LENGTH]
                              [-o] [-s SIZE]

Serg's XML slideshow creator

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DIRECTORY, --directory DIRECTORY
                        Directory where images stored. Required
  -t TRANSITION, --transition TRANSITION
                        transition time in seconds, default 2.5
  -l LENGTH, --length LENGTH
                        Time length in seconds per image, default 1800
  -o, --overlay         Enables use of overlay transition
  -s SIZE, --size SIZE  wallpaper,zoom,centered,scaled,stretched,or spanned
```

#### Script Source

The script source is available both here and on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/xml_wallpaper_maker.py). If you have `git`, feel free to run `git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git`  or download the repository files from the link above. If you're copying from here, make sure you save the file as `xml_wallpaper_maker.py` and make it executable with `chmod +x xml_wallpaper_maker.py`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

#
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com
# Date: September 2 , 2016
# Purpose: A program that creates and launches XML slideshow
#      
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
#
#
# Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
# See included LICENSE file or the notice below.
#
# Copyright © 2016 Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
# in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.


from gi.repository import Gio
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree as etree
import argparse
import sys
import os

def gsettings_set(schema, path, key, value):
    """Set value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema, path)
    if isinstance(value,list ):
        return gsettings.set_strv(key, value)
    if isinstance(value,int):
        return gsettings.set_int(key, value)
    if isinstance(value,str):
        return gsettings.set_string(key,value)

def parse_args():
        """ Parses command-line arguments """
        arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Serg\'s XML slideshow creator',
        )

        arg_parser.add_argument(
                                '-d', '--directory',
                                help='Directory where images stored. Required',
                                type=str,
                                required=True
                                )

        arg_parser.add_argument(
                                '-t','--transition', 
                                type=float,
                                default=2.5,
                                help='transition time in seconds, default 2.5',
                                required=False
                                )


        arg_parser.add_argument(
                                '-l','--length', 
                                type=float,
                                default=1800.0,
                                help='Time length in seconds per image, default 1800',
                                required=False
                                )

        arg_parser.add_argument(
                                '-o','--overlay', 
                                action='store_true',
                                help='Enables use of overlay transition',
                                required=False
                                )

        arg_parser.add_argument(
                                '-s','--size', 
                                type=str,
                                help='wallpaper,zoom,centered,scaled,stretched,or spanned',
                                default='scaled',
                                required=False
                                )
        return arg_parser.parse_args()



def main():
    """ Program entry point"""
    args = parse_args()
    xml_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'.local/share/slideshow.xml')
    path = os.path.abspath(args.directory)
    duration = args.length
    transition_time = args.transition

    if not os.path.isdir(path):
       print(path," is not a directory !")
       sys.exit(1)

    filepaths = [os.path.join(path,item) for item in os.listdir(path) ]
    images = [ img for img in filepaths if os.path.isfile(img)]
    filepaths = None
    images.sort()
    root = ET.Element("background")
    previous = None

    # Write the xml data of images and transitions
    for index,img in enumerate(images):

        if index == 0:
           previous = img
           continue

        image = ET.SubElement(root, "static")
        ET.SubElement(image,"duration").text = str(duration)
        ET.SubElement(image,"file").text = previous

        if args.overlay: 
            transition = ET.SubElement(root,"transition",type='overlay')
        else:
            transition = ET.SubElement(root,"transition")
        ET.SubElement(transition,"duration").text = str(transition_time)
        ET.SubElement(transition, "from").text = previous
        ET.SubElement(transition, "to").text = img

        previous = img

    # Write out the final image
    image = ET.SubElement(root, "static")
    ET.SubElement(image,"duration").text = str(duration)
    ET.SubElement(image,"file").text = previous

    # Write out the final xml data to file
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    tree.write(xml_file)

    # pretty print the data
    data = etree.parse(xml_file)
    formated_xml = etree.tostring(data, pretty_print = True)
    with open(xml_file,'w') as f:
        f.write(formated_xml.decode())


    gsettings_set('org.gnome.desktop.background',None,'picture-options', args.size)
    gsettings_set('org.gnome.desktop.background',None,'picture-uri','file://' + xml_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```