# Creating your own custom wallpaper that changes at regular interval

Tags: desktop-background

`/usr/share/background/xenial.xml` has xml syntax to change wallpapers, which specifies specific UTC/local day time  to change wallpaper.

1. How to create custom `xenial.xml` which changes every 5 mins irrespective of UTC/local time ?
2. From where I can find documentation for all the available syntax for creating wallpaper that changes automatically?
3. Currently my version is Xenial Xerus if I upgrade to Zesty Zapus, may I  have to make some changes `xenial.xml`.

Comment: I've written a script like a year agi that allows creating slideshows . See the
related post https://askubuntu.com/a/840381/295286    Documentation doesn't really exist, just ubuntu wiki page:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SlideshowWallpapers